# Which stock has split more than once in the past five years?

Tags: stock-split

For testing reasons I am looking for a stock that has been split more than once in the past five years.

Comment: Does it have to be the last 5 years, or multiples in any 5 year period?

Answer (score 6):

Here are the companies on the S&P 500 that split more than once in the last five years:

```
Under Armour (3 splits)
AFLAC (2 splits)
Brown-Forman (2 splits)
Fiserv (2 splits)
Johnson Controls International (2 splits)
Nike (2 splits)
Smith (A O)  (2 splits)
Twenty-First Century Fox  (2 splits)
```

Hadn't looked into this before, kind of fun. In a 17 year period (1982-1999) Home Depot split 13 times. Dollar General, Oracle, and Southwest Airlines have all split 11 times.

Comment: Fascinating, I stupidly assumed the answer would be 100s of companies.

Comment: It is hundreds of companies, if you include OTC-listed ones.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the leaders with the highest split count since 16 Aug 2013, categorized by split type.

## Standard stock splits

NYSE:HEI (Heico Corp) had four splits.  Each were 5:4 splits with the following ex-dates: 20180626, 20180118, 20170419, 20131203

Others with three splits: Nasdaq:BIO, Nasdaq: CARO, Nasdaq:LINK, Nasdaq:TQQQ

## Reverse splits

If we incorporate reverse splits too, the following top the list:

Nasdaq:DRYS (DryShips Inc) - 8 splits.  7:1 reverse split 20170721, 5:1 reverse split 20170622, 7:1 reverse split 20170511, 4:1 reverse split 20170411, 8:1 reverse split 20170123, 15:1 reverse split 20161101, 4:1 reverse split 20160815, 25:1 reverse split 20160311.

Nasdaq:TOPS (Top Ships inc) - 7 splits.  10:1 reverse split 20180326, 2:1 reverse split 20171006, 30:1 reverse split 20170803, 15:1 reverse split 20170623, 20:1 reverse split 20170511, 10:1 reverse

Nasdaq:DCIX had 6 splits

Nasdaq:TVIX, UVXY, JDST, JNUG, NUGT each had 5 splits.

## Stock dividends

If we incorporate "stock dividends in the same stock" (which is essentially a smaller version of a stock split), then this one is the clear winner:

NYSE:EEQ (Enbridge Energy Management) - has had 20 stock dividends - their pattern is one every 3 months.

Nasdaq:UBFO had 15 stock dividends.

## All time greatest number since 1950

Incorporating forward splits, reverse splits and stock dividends, the top ten are:

1. Delisted:GP-200512 (Georgia Pacific Corp) (delisted Dec 2005) - 79
2. Delisted:ILA-200807 (Aquila Inc) (delisted Jul 2008) - 78
3. Delisted:CZN-199708 (Citizens Communications Co) (delisted Aug 1997) - 66
4. Delisted:BSH-197510 (Bush Universal Inc) (delisted Oct 1975) - 61
5. NYSE:TR (Tootsie Roll Industries Inc) - 60
6. NYSE:EEQ (Enbridge Energy Management LLC) - 55
7. Nasdaq:FTR (Frontier Communcations Corp) - 46
8. Nasdaq:ACET (Aceto Corp) - 40
9. Nasdaq:UBFO (United Security Bancshares) - 38
10. NYSE:PVH (PVH Corp) - 37

Note:  This does not include US stocks that trade OTC.

---

Data source:  Various internal databases at Norgate Data.  Disclosure:  Norgate Data is a data vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Leveraged ETFs are very volatile and regularly do forward splits (if they're lucky) or reverse splits (if they're not). One of the lucky ones, TQQQ, has forward split [three times in the past five years](https://www.splithistory.com/tqqq/).

Answer (score -1):

There's a long list of stock splits at https://www.splithistory.com/technology/ but you're going to have to click on symbols one by one and read the descriptions.

There are sites that list splits by the month but you'd have to do some data scraping to collect a historical list, one month at a time. For example, Fidelity.

And then there's the old fashioned Google, hoping to get lucky :->)

Comment: I understand I can find that data myself, after technically scrawling a lot of data. I just wondered whether anyone had a top-of-mind stock that went through multiple splits past five years. It seems uncommon.